# nodejs azure keyvault certificate

Tags: node.js, typescript, certificate, azure-keyvault

i get a certificate from an azure key vault :

```
const certificate = await keyVaultClient.getCertificate(this.keyVaultUri, certificateName, '');
```

i get the certificate ... first good thing :)

But after i don't find how i can set the certificate in the header of an https request.

i've tried different ways without any success.

Someone knows how i can achieve that. Below test done.

```
var options = {
    hostname: 'url.domain.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/method1',
    method: 'GET',
    agent: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    strictSSL: false,
    //pfx: certificate.cer.toString('utf8'),
    //pfx: certificate.cer.toString('base64'),
    pfx: certificate,
    passphrase: 'passphrase'

  };

const req = https.request(options, (res: any) => { });
```

Note that if i use the certificate on the drive, it works :

```
pfx: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/my.pfx'),
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've found a solution.

First to get the certificate, i've used the method 'getSercret' in place of 'getCertificate' :

`let keyVaultClient = new KeyVault.KeyVaultClient(azureCredential);
 const secret = await keyVaultClient.getSecret(this.keyVaultUri, secretName, '');`

In the header option, i've passed the secret in a buffer with base 64 format :

```
var options = {
                hostname: 'myurl.ti',
                port: 443,
                path: '/mySuperMethod',
                method: 'GET',
                agent: false,
                rejectUnauthorized: false,
                strictSSL: false,
                pfx: new Buffer(secret.value, 'base64'),
                passphrase: ''
            };
```

You see that the passphrase (password to secure password) is empty. Why ? in fact when you upload a certificate in azure keyvault, you have to mention the password. But after keyvault doesn't keep the password and it's set to blank.

That's known by microsoft and for me it's an issue.

Here an article that explain that : https://thuansoldier.net/7462/

Regards Mathieu